# CSS Divs overlapping absolute

Tags: html, css, overlap

Here's my CSS: http://pastebin.com/UZdSssK8
Here's my HTML: http://pastebin.com/vJcB9nLu

Whenever I drag my Firefox window down smaller, #centre starts overlapping with div.left. #centre should be slightly off centred to the left. I want it to be able to fluidly move, but never overlap ANY text on the left hand side.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

too much positioning really, and because you're always positioning the divs/spans a percentage from the left side that is bound to cause an overlap eventuall, what you need is to give at least one of you column a width (and you have that "snap" with a width of 184px) so you know that the right side has to be at least 184, + and "margins" from the left side

however I'd advise to lose the positioning altogether as @JackWilson suggests, AP (absolute positioning) should be used sparingly, not really advisable for entire layouts unless you're after a UI type interface  - then when it is used it's best to at least have it inside an element that is positioned relatively so it's taking it's position from an element that is already in the flow.

here's a **[working Sample in JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/ixuso4)**

I've coloured the backgrounds so you can "see" the divs, this is often a good idea when developing too.. btw the way you also don't need to specify display block on either a floated or an AP'd element  they automatically are blocks once those properties are applied

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use absolute positioning in this exact manner. Absolute positioning removes the element from the document's normal flow. It's as if the elements don't interact with each other as they normally would - as in this case a div could not normally overlap another div.

Unfortunately, without knowing more about how you're actually trying to lay these elements out, I can't give you an alternative. Could you explain a bit more or draw a diagram of what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/dkrEK/

Try this:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
    <link type="text/css" href="ssc.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>kd</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="left">
            <span class="head">
                <a href="#">kd</a>
            </span>
            <div class="snap">
                about me blah blah blah blah blah blah test
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="centre">
            test <br />
            test
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.head {
    font-family:courier-new,monospace;
    font-size:200%;
}
.head > a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
div.left {
    top:35%;
    position:absolute;
    margin-right:50px;

    width: 200px;
    float: left;
}
#centre {
    top:38%;
    font-family:courier-new,monospace;
    font-size:80%;

    position:absolute;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 200px;
}
div.snap {
    font-family:courier-new,monospace;
    font-size:80%;
    padding-top:5px;
    width: 95%;
    left:2%;
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: `position: absolute` and `float` don't go together, there should only be one or the other. Used together like this the float isn't doing anything  - though I would be suggesting floats and widths though :)

Comment: @clairesuzy - Thanks for that. I didn't really proof-read the CSS. I just tried make it work haha. =) Removing the `float` from both `div.left` and `#centre` won't really affect the output.

Comment: you're welcome, good job, you're right removing the floats don't affect the output  - it's working fine because of the widths whichever way it's done :)